# GTest test case "EXPECT_CALL" compilation error

Tags: c++, testing, googletest, googlemock

```
#include "gtest\gtest.h"
using namespace testing;

class MyGTest : public Test
{
public:
    void f(){}
    void g(){
        f();
        f();
    }
};

TEST_F(MyGTest, first)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*this, f()).Times(2);
    g();
}
```

VC2013 says:

```
    "MyGTest_first_Test" has no member "gmock_f"
```

What does it mean? I expect the call to g() to call f() for 2 times. Any syntax error I made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a syntax error, more like a completely wrong approach. Macro
`EXPECT_CALL` is used to set expectations of function calls from
mock objects. The problem is that you are not passing a mock
object to `EXPECT_CALL` (an object of class whose definition contains
`MOCK_METHODN`), you are dereferencing `this` pointer instead. In
doing so, you are passing an object of your test class to `EXPECT_CALL`.
This is why the compiler error mentiones class `MyGTest_first_Test`,
gmock creates a new class in the background, and its name is a
combination of fixture class name (`MyGTest`), test case name
(`first`) and base class name (`Test`).